# Select specific object from a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, rss, winjs

I'm working with a windows 8 app using **Java Script**

I'm get some rss and convert it to JSON format objects using Google API. So Then I got some sort of object array of JSON  for that rss feed. I need to do is I want to select few objects among all objects of the array according to the published day. That means I want to get all objects from the array which published before 6 hours(In between current date and before 6 hours except other objects).. Can anyone help me for do that..?

I use this code for get all objects.

```
function loadNews() {
var allEntries = [];   
var pendingRequestCount = listOfFeed.length;
var onRequestFinished = function () {
    pendingRequestCount--;
    if (pendingRequestCount === 0) {
        processItems(allEntries);           
    }
};

for (var x = 0; x < listOfFeed.length; x++) {

        feedburnerUrl = listOfFeed[x].url,
            feedUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=999&q=" + encodeURIComponent(feedburnerUrl);
        WinJS.xhr({
            url: feedUrl,
            responseType: "rss/json"
        }).done(function complete(result) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.response);
            var entries = jsonData.responseData.feed.entries;
            allEntries = allEntries.concat(entries);

            allEntries.sort(function (entry1, entry2) {// Compare the entries by publish date
                return Date.parse(entry2.publishedDate) - Date.parse(entry1.publishedDate); // return get milisecond
            });
            onRequestFinished();
        });
    }  //loop x finish}
```

}

According to the above cord, **allEntries** provide JSON object array

Very thankful for the your answers

Comment: Provide us with at least a part of the JSON, so we can know what we are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to loop through every entry and compare the dates. For each date that passes your test, add it to another array. E.g.

```
var newEntries = JSON.parse(result.response),
    filteredEntries = [],
    i,
    testDate = new Date();

testDate = testDate.setHours(testDate.getHours() - 6);

for(i = 0; i < newEntries.length; i++) {
    if(newEntries[i].publishedDate > testDate) {
        filteredEntries.push(newEntries[i]);
    }
}
```

`new Date()` always returns the current date

`Date.getHours()` returns the hour component of the date

`Date.setHours(hour)` sets the hour component of the date

If `hour` is a negative value, the date will go to the previous day. For instance if your date was `2013-5-3 04:33` setting the `hour` component to `-2` will change the date to `2013-5-2 22:33`

In the example above, if the time was 2:45 a.m., it will set the time component to -4, which would cause it to test against 8:45 p.m. the previous day.

Comment: **Vincent McNabb** Thank you very much for your kind support. It really works for me. Thanks again..